# warning: comparison between pointer and integer and Segment fault in C

Tags: c, terminal, linux-mint

I'm implementing a basic SJF algorithm. This one just sorts the processes contingent on the burst times and sorts the respective process number at the same time. `b[]` is an array for bursts and `p[]` stores the process numbers. I'm getting the following error on compiling:

```
sjf.c: In function ‘main’:
sjf.c:23:10: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
sjf.c:25:10: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
sjf.c:39:10: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
```

Not just this but after I run the program in Linux Mint 15's terminal,the execution terminates on grounds of a 'Segmentation Fault'. The following is a sample output:

```
enter number of jobs2
Enter burst time12
21
Segmentation fault
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

main()
{
    int k;
    int c;
    int b[100];
    int n[100];
    int a;
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("enter number of jobs");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter burst time");

    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
        n[i]=i;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
        {
            if(b[j]>b[j+1])
            {
                k=b[j];
                b[j]=b[j+1];
                b[j+1]=k;

                c=n[j];
                n[j]=n[j+1];
                n[j+1]=n[j];
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("burst time for process %d = %d ",n[i],b[i]);
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You forgot to press `<tab>` a couple of times...

Comment: I am surprised by ouah's answer!!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; True. First few minutes I was thinking that I made this mistake many times but why my compiler didn't warned me!! LOLz

Answer (score 0):

`n` is array in your code declared as `int n[100];`, in for loops condition `n` should be `a`:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
               ^ 
for(j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
               ^ 
                both should be a
```

Similar mistake is in last for loop where you prints.

So in programming naming convention matters, and indentation also very important.

Comment: God I can't believe I did this. Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: @Zepp93; Better way of saying thanks here is by reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and implementing it after reading :).

Comment: @Zepp93 But you have to :), notice precisely the indentation given by Joshua Taylor in your code, additionally how I written for loop. Also keep space after `;`, `,`, `:` and expressions like   `a=b-c;` should be written as `a = b - c;`. Additionally your naming conversion is not good,  `a` could be **a** rray name, `n` could be **n** umber!